# Nested UL in LI overlays content

Tags: html, css

In the below HTML snippet, I have a UL within an LI (basic tree view design).  For some reason which I cant work out, my nested UL displays over the below content, it doesn't push it down.

[image]

I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0jum264y/)

I don't have position:absolute on any elements.  Can anyone see any thing which would make this behaviour occur?  Thanks.

```html
 <style type="text/css">

    .treeul {
        padding-left: 25px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 9pt;
        position: relative;
    }

    .treeli {
        margin: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        height: 16px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .folderlicollapsed {
        padding: 0px;
        /*list-style-image: url('Images/ClosedFolder.gif')*/
    }

    .folderli {
        /*list-style-image: url('Images/OpenFolder.gif');*/
        padding: 0px
    }

    .measureli {
        list-style-image: url('Images/Measure.gif');
        padding: 0px
    }

    .dimli {
        list-style-image: url('Images/Dimension.gif');
        padding: 0px
    }

    .operanddiv {
        border: solid #808080 1px;
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 9pt;
        white-space: nowrap
    }
</style>

 <div style="border:solid silver 1px;border-radius:3px;padding:2px;height:260px;overflow:auto;" id="xdivObjectTree">
    <ul class="trueeul">
        <li class="treeli folderli" id="24e2aadb-d07c-4307-8fea-1e26038cda6e" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('24e2aadb-d07c-4307-8fea-1e26038cda6e')" loaded="true">
            <div>Attributes</div>                
        <div>
            <ul class="trueeul">
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="ee09c67e-3bc1-46cf-8755-3374a675fecb" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('ee09c67e-3bc1-46cf-8755-3374a675fecb')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">DataBank mapping</div>
                </li>
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="7ae9f641-c9c5-47bf-899e-b1a3c5652702" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('7ae9f641-c9c5-47bf-899e-b1a3c5652702')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">Geographical Location</div>
                </li>
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="6a84573c-cd69-4599-83a8-c4093b93d04a" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('6a84573c-cd69-4599-83a8-c4093b93d04a')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">Operation Type</div>
                </li>
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="cc1d3e5a-7790-4b3b-89e0-f9d6cf37cf6a" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('cc1d3e5a-7790-4b3b-89e0-f9d6cf37cf6a')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">Organisational Structure</div>
                </li>
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="be205c26-6708-4ecc-b66b-3c3ba6e734b3" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('be205c26-6708-4ecc-b66b-3c3ba6e734b3')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">Product Grouping</div>
                </li>
                <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="735dec54-c717-47d7-9cf1-4510056aa465" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('735dec54-c717-47d7-9cf1-4510056aa465')" loaded="true">
                    <div style="margin:0px">Reporting Members</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="4e845a75-3fec-4b60-887d-c9c34d623507" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('4e845a75-3fec-4b60-887d-c9c34d623507')" loaded="true"><div style="margin:0px">Data Element</div></li>
        <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="2281cf50-7d89-40f3-b65a-148040ee8734" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('2281cf50-7d89-40f3-b65a-148040ee8734')" loaded="false"><div style="margin:0px">GreenHouse</div></li>
        <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="e9b473fb-ad56-468f-9656-a39b7364dae6" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('e9b473fb-ad56-468f-9656-a39b7364dae6')" loaded="false"><div style="margin:0px">Production</div></li>
        <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed" id="5cebc8b5-172e-4b47-8ee9-c056858775a8" onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('5cebc8b5-172e-4b47-8ee9-c056858775a8')" loaded="false"><div style="margin:0px">HSEC Targets</div></li>
        <li class="treeli folderlicollapsed"
            id="7624f8ef-0c05-4dec-b14b-046fe1794157"
            onclick="ToggleConditionFolder('7624f8ef-0c05-4dec-b14b-046fe1794157')"
            loaded="false"><div style="margin:0px">Filters</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When you remove all css its ok, but remove this,  height: 16px;
            position: relative;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined an height for your `<li>` which is preventing its content being displayed properly.

If you change the property `height` to `min-height` for class `.treeli` it will work as espected ;)

Comment: Ja, total wundershon, its jetz eine tolle antworten.